# Windows 7 swaps screen contents upon de-hibernation

Tags: windows-7, video, multiple-monitors

I have a AMD 64 bit Windows 7 Ultimate running with a built-in ATI Radeon 3200 graphics adapter, on which I have two screens connected, a VGA CRT and a DVI LCD.

The screens have different resolutions. The system is configured to extend the desktop on both screens.

Whenever the system comes out of hibernation, the contents of the screen are swapped, including the task bar. The relative position of the screens remain the same.

I am reasonably sure that the display driver is up to date (version 8.56.1.15 by ATI).

Has anyone seen that problem? Solved it?

Comment: I have the same exact issue - haven't tested hibernate but it happens on every reboot. Pisses me off. What's worse? If you're moving your mouse as it starts up, the layout is correct then, just as you get the prompt to log in it changes back.

Comment: Does it get the resolutions right?

Comment: @soandos: for mine, yes. It stays at 1280x1024 for both (yay 5:4!...) Mine is a ATI Radeon HD 3400, monitor 2 is the primary with monitor 1 to the left. When I reboot, monitor 2 keeps the taskbar (stays primary) but monitor 1 moves to the right.

Comment: The problem is only when you wake up from hibernation or with every fresh reboot.

Comment: @avirk: My situation is slightly different than edmx's. Mine occurs after a reboot and I just confirmed it does NOT happen after hibernation. I happened to offer a bounty on this because my situation is very similar to edmx's.

Comment: Hmmm sounds very odd never saw or face this kind of problem.

Comment: Dehibernation? I believe the opposite of hibernation is called estivation. :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the ports that the screens are connected to? (Is this a viable option for your setup?)

Also, have you tried completely uninstalling the driver and all applications (Catalyst Control Center, etc.) and then reinstalling? It sounds like it is applying some configuration file after it loads (Windows does the same thing with my nVidia cards-- the configuration doesn't get activated until shortly after the login screen is displayed).

Comment: I'll give it a shot tomorrow morning but something had changed. For over a year it was fine and then about a month or two ago it started acting up like this.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. It was pretty neat watching Windows reposition the monitors as I changed inputs while it was plugged in (so the layout was automatically correct after switching) but the problem persisted. After reboot it looked like it was ok and then partway through typing in my password it reset again. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I would try uninstalling the video drivers and reinstalling the video drivers (catalyst control center, the whole works). It sounds like it's still trying to apply some setting after it loads, perhaps reinstalling will clear the configuration and fix the issue.

Comment: It was never using the ATI catalyst drivers, just the inbox Windows 7 drivers (and anything through Windows Update). I installed 11.6 catalyst and still the same issue. Though this time it seemed to apply *after* I started to log in, the layout was fine as I waited on the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you have the latest driver from the Radeon site, and latest chipset driver from the motherboard manufacturer ?

Unless I made a mistake, the latest [Radeon driver versions](http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.7&product=2.7.4.3.3.3.1&contentType=Tech%20Download%20Chipset%20Motherboard&ostype=&keywords=windows%20driver&items=20) are 10.9 for 32-bits and 11.6 for 64-bits.

Comment: I'll try it again. Tried it about a month ago with Catalyst 11.5 and it bluescreened Windows 7 when detecting the card. (Go figure, my first BSOD in a long, long time)

Comment: Thanks, running Catalyst 11.6 and still experience the same issue. On this last reboot it seemed to revert *after* I started the login process. While I waited on the login screen for the Ctrl+Alt+Del message it was ok, I enter my password and hit enter and it reset. Agh!

Comment: Maybe you can disable PowerPlay as described [here](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=260&threadid=100048) in Spyral's 2nd answer. (Can't test this, as I always preferred Nvidia to Radeon). Backup any file you change.

Comment: Did you try disabling PowerPlay ?

Comment: Yes, and unfortunately it did not make any difference. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: If the main monitor is late to wake up, to secondary may take over as the primary. you could check if the power settings of the two monitors do differ in Device Manager.

Comment: Both seem to wake up at the same time and have the same settings in Device Manager. Unfortunately, the issue isn't that the primary monitor switches inputs (it doesn't) it's that the monitor layout swaps back to default (meaning the secondary monitor moves from the left of the primary monitor to the right of the primary).

Comment: I don't understand then *why* you have this problem. I would try in your case to use a desktop extender, rather than rely on Windows. One that comes to mind is [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) - it is not free but has a trial version.

Answer (score 0):

It's unresolved issue in many graphics. I've got the same on many Dell D530 with external screens. In situation when main screen was Laptop screen, everything was fine - in situation when external screen was main - every restart changed all configuration (swaped screens)

I've searched many forums, try diffrent drivers, callcenters - nothing. Now I'm preaty sure it's unresolved on my Dell's ;)

Try changing "main" screens, try both DVI cables - It happens only when computer comes out of hibernation?